# Job listing page needs some CSS luvin

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The job listing page has a mixture of `<h>` tags with various styles and colors that makes the page <strike>hideous</strike> not so nice.  There seems to be a mix of h3 / h2 / h1 tags with various weights (some bold) and various orange colors.

Can this page be cleaned up a bit so that it is more consistent.  Here's the <strike>ugly duckling</strike> beauty:

[image]

Be nice if these headers were a bit more standard across this page and the link to the company page was a bit cleaner, seems awfully big.

Comment: Very true. Fix incoming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see the updated Job Detail view on prod; styles have been cleaned up and made consistent. In the next week or so, we'll be testing additional improvements to the view. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Seriously - check out the image I posted above compared what you have now, isn't it much better?